# Rotate Labels and Change colors of tikz barchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color, rotating, bar-chart

I am creating a bar chart using tikzpicture like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\title{test}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={RSA1024,RSA2048,RSA4096,Kyber512,Kyber768,Kyber1024}, xtick=data]
        \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
            (RSA1024,483)
            (RSA2048,489)
            (RSA4096,536)
            (Kyber512,120)
            (Kyber768,111)
            (Kyber1024,143)
        };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This currently looks like this:

[image]

However, the labels are nearly overlapping each other which doesn't look great.
I would like them to be rotated at a, say, 60 degree angle. How can I do this?

Secondly, I want the 3 rightmost bars to have a different color then the 3 on the left.
I want the 3 on the left to be blue and the three on right to be orange. How can I do this? I tried using addplot multiple time in the same picture, but that doesnt work.

Here is a picture of how I want these changes to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different colors can be obtained using addplot multiple time in the same picture. Option `xticklabel style={xshift=-10pt, rotate=60}` rotates labels and shift them to the right, so they become adjacent on the bars.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={RSA1024,RSA2048,RSA4096,Kyber512,Kyber768,Kyber1024}, 
        xtick={RSA1024,RSA2048,RSA4096,Kyber512,Kyber768,Kyber1024}, 
        xticklabel style={xshift=-10pt, rotate=60}]
        \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
            (RSA1024,483)
            (RSA2048,489)
            (RSA4096,536)
        };
        \addplot[ybar,fill=orange] coordinates {
            (Kyber512,120)
            (Kyber768,111)
            (Kyber1024,143)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `xticklabel style={xshift=-10pt, rotate=60}` I would use `ticklabel style={font=\small},
        xticklabel style={rotate=60, anchor=north east}]`

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for. And yes, I will try `font=\small`, especially because its currently not possible to have two graphs on one page