# Merge 3 bar plots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to merge 3 bar plots

```
       \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}  
                \begin{axis}  
                [  
                    ybar,  
                    xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=north east}, 
                    %ylabel={\# Parameters ($*10^6$)},
                    symbolic x coords={A, B, C, D, E}, 
                    bar width=10pt,
                    xtick=data,  
                    nodes near coords,
                    nodes near coords align={vertical},  
                    ymin=-0,
                    ]  
                \addplot coordinates {(A,2.98) (B,50) (C,50) (D, 23) (E, 138) };  
                 % 
                \end{axis}  
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \begin{tikzpicture}  
                    \begin{axis}  
                    [  
                        ybar,  
                        xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=north east}, 
                        %ylabel={\# Parameters ($*10^6$)}, 
                        symbolic x coords={F, G, H}, 
                        bar width=10pt,
                        xtick=data,  
                        nodes near coords,  
                        nodes near coords align={vertical},  
                        ymin=-0,
                        ]  
                    \addplot[fill=green!40] coordinates {(F,2.98) (G,50) (H,50)};  
                     % 
                    \end{axis}  
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}  
                        \begin{axis}  
                        [  
                            ybar,  
                            xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=north east}, 
                            %ylabel={\# Parameters ($*10^6$)},
                            symbolic x coords={I, J, K, L}, 
                            bar width=10pt,
                            xtick=data,  
                            nodes near coords,  
                            nodes near coords align={vertical},  
                            ymin=-0,
                            ]  
                        \addplot[fill=red!40] coordinates {(I,2.98) (J,50) (K,50) (L, 23)};  
                         % 
                        \end{axis}  
                        \end{tikzpicture}  
            \caption{WIP}
        \end{figure}
```

[image]

I would like to have these 3 groups of colored bars in one axis (perhaps the blue ones grouped on the left, the green ones in the middle, and the red ones on the right). How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Did you try to put those 3 `\addplot` into the same `axis` environment and merge the `symbolic x coords`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650756/42803 for example